# C#: Using List as Dictionary value. Value will does not get stored in dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm having trouble with this bit of code.  I'm new to C#, but from what I've done so far I'm drawing the conclusion that dictionaries are only references, and do not actually store data?

```
           foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in range1.Rows)
            {
                string upc;
                upc = row.Cells[1, 2].Value2;
                list.Add(upc);
                list.Add(row.Cells[1, 3].Value2);
                list.Add("6");


                //add row to dictionary
                dictionary.Add(row.Cells[1, 1].Value2, list);
```

}

In this example, if I keep this loop going for every row in range1, it will add every row's data to the list.  IE, the last item in the dictionary will contain each attribute for all of the rows in the range.  I tried clearing the list after every iteration, but then the dictionary reports that there is no value, leading me to believe that I must have a separate list created for each dictionary entry?  How can I do this, and is this the most efficient way?  Something seems off.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the list to be an aggregate of every cell, or is it doing that and you don't want it to? The part about the dictionary being empty makes no sense to me unless you had an exception thrown and it never added anything to the dictionary. Are you sure row.Cells[x, y].Value2 is actually returning the data you want? I can't remember but it seems like the new MS Office library for .NET kept the cell values in a cache separate from the cells so you had to take a reference out of the cell and cross-reference with the values table.

Comment: Nevermind about my comment about the ms office library. Duh you are using the old Interop one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's only one list in your code, and a reference to it is stored as the value for each dictionary key.  You want to create a new List at each loop iteration and add it to the dictionary.

Comment: Okay, this is what I wanted to hear as it confirms what I was thinking.  In that case, how would I create a new list at the beginning of each loop iteration..if the number of lists is dynamic, and changes everytime the program is run?

Comment: List<string> lst = new List<string>

Comment: @user1739730 Add "list = new List<string>();" before the line with "list.Add(upc);"

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you aren't quite grasping is `List<T>` is a reference type.  That means when you store it in a location, be it a property in a class or as a value in a `Dictionary<TKey,List<T>>`, any change will affect that list in every location that reference is saved.  For example:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
Dictionary<Int32, List<String>> dict = new Dictionary<Int32, List<String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    list.Add("String" + i);
    dict.Add(i, list);
}
```

This is somewhat close to what you are trying to do.

But if you write the output out:

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", kvp.Key);

    foreach (var item in kvp.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    Value: {0}", item);        
    }
}
```

If I am reading you expectations correctly, this is what I think you think is going to appear:

```
Key: 0
    Value: String0
Key: 1
    Value: String0
    Value: String1
Key: 2
    Value: String0
    Value: String1
    Value: String2
Key: 3
    Value: String0
    Value: String1
    Value: String2
    Value: String3
```

But the actual output is:

```
Key: 0
    Value: String0
    Value: String1
    Value: String2
    Value: String3
Key: 1
    Value: String0
    Value: String1
    Value: String2
    Value: String3
Key: 2
    Value: String0
    Value: String1
    Value: String2
    Value: String3
Key: 3
    Value: String0
    Value: String1
    Value: String2
    Value: String3
```

This is because you are adding the **same** List to the dictionary for each key, and any time you make a change, be it add a new value, or clear it (with `List.Clear()`), you are changing every occurrence of that same list.

Answer (score 0):

The `Dictionary` isn't a reference, but in this case it *contains* references.

`Lists` are also not 'references', but they are accessed and manipulated through references. If you add a `List` to something, you are added a reference to that `List`, not a copy.

Reference types are typically only copied when you explicitly specify that you want to copy or create a new instance.

Answer (score -1):

`Dictionary<string, List<string>>` should be the dictionary. Your code should work. If the dictionary has the key, the .Add will throw an exception. Make sure the dictionary is outside of the loop.

Comment: Dictionary is outside the loop.  The lists are added to the dictionary fine, it's just that if I clear the list at each iteration, the dictionary value for that specific key is gone (even though I clear it after "Dictionary.add(key, list);"

Comment: I think you need a value copy instead of reference copy. Create a new List after the loop and copy the list like `new List<string>(list).